# Why does converting an int to Character wrapper object suffix '\u000' before each character?

Tags: java, character, wrapper

Following is the solution for finding the single differing additional alphabet between two strings.

```
 public char findTheDifference(String s, String t) {
        int sSum = 0;
        int tSum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            sSum = sSum + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)); 
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < t.length(); j++){
            tSum = tSum + Character.getNumericValue(t.charAt(j));
        }
        return (char)(tSum-sSum);    
    }
```

It returns '\u000e' instead of 'e'.

Example input:

```
String1 = "abcd"
String2 = "abecd"
```

Output= `"e"`

Questions:
1) Why is it returning '\u000e'? I understand that if I remove `Character.getNumericValue` within both `for loops`, I get 'e'. But I want to understand why using it adds \u000?

Comment: Let's assume the input is "Helle" and "Hello". What is the value of (tSum - sSum)? What happens when this value is cast to an char? Even more interesting, what happens when the input is "Hello" and "Helle" -- what is the result going to be then? Also, look up the value for Unicode `\u000e` -- might be of relevance.

Comment: The input is always going to be one additional alphabet differing between two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Character.getNumericValue()` converts a character to a number, using particular rules [explained here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-).

In particular, the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` that you're using get converted to the numbers 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 - this method assumes you intended them to be digits in a number system like hexadecimal.